# Autologin to the website via Active-Directory

Tags: javascript, active-directory, autologin

I was faced with the need to implement pass-through authentication for my website. It supposed to work automatically and should use the credentials of the respective active-directory-user. Is it possible and if so, how? Most importantly, I do not understand how to get user credentials for login.

It's Javascript ECMA 5.1 on client side, and java for server.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? Worth reading how to ask a query: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236

Comment: You need a ldap client server-side with ldap-credentials to connect to the ldap-server (you need at least read rights) and then query the sAMAccountName. If you don't have a clue what all that means, I suggest you clue yourself up a bit about [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) and [AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)

Comment: yea! I understand what i need to do on server side! No problem if user can enter input. But the problem is, how to take ldap-credentials in js code by browser from win? i

Comment: This might help (if you are not using IIS for your web server): http://spnego.sourceforge.net